# How to show alert in all controllers without repeating the code?

Tags: ios, swift, alert, appdelegate

I want to write one function `alert()` and to run it. But I want to show this alert in any controllers without repeating the code.

For example: I have Presence.swift class and here I have some condition, as:

```
if myVar == 1 { // Just for presenting
    runMyAlert()
}
```

and when in the background `myVar == 1` user, regardless of the fact that where he is, on which screen, he gets alert on screen.

How can I do it without repeating my code? I tried to make it in AppDelegate as:

```
func alert(title : String,message : String,buttonTitle : String,window: UIWindow){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    window.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And call it as:

```
if myVar == 1 {
    AppDelegate().alert()
}
```

Comment: u can write some code to get the current top viewcontroller then u can present it from anywhere....`rootViewController` is different from your current top viewcontroller

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Developing on `Swift` you should know about protocols which can solve your problem easily. You can create a new protocol `MyAlert` and make default implementation for `UIViewController` class. And then just inherit your `MyAlert` protocol in view controller, where you need it, and call the function!

```
protocol MyAlert {
    func runMyAlert()
}

extension MyAlert where Self: UIViewController {
    func runMyAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "buttonTitle", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So you can implement and call it like that:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyAlert {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        runMyAlert() // for test
    }
}
```

UPD:

code for your case:

```
protocol MyAlert {
    func runMyAlert()
}

extension MyAlert where Self: UIViewController {
    func runMyAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "buttonTitle", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class OpenChatsTableViewController: UITableViewController, MyAlert, OneRosterDelegate, BuddyRequestProtocol {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        runMyAlert()
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the next error: `Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MyAlert'`

Comment: Show your code, maybe you forgot to inherit `UIViewController` for your `ViewController`

Comment: This is my class where I use this protocol: `class OpenChatsTableViewController: UITableViewController, OneRosterDelegate, BuddyRequestProtocol {` also I modified this line of code `extension MyAlert where Self: UIViewController` to this `extension MyAlert where Self: UITableViewController`

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade don't modify it, `UITableViewController` inherits `UIViewController`

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade I added code specially for your controller name - see it

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade it's because in protocol your declare `showBuddyRequest()` and in extension you implement `showBuddyRequest(fromUser: String)` - it's 2 different functions. Hope, you know how to solve it. In my example, there 2 same functions with same params

Answer (score 2):

Create a category on UIViewController, write a method there, calling which app will show an alert box.

Now create a new BaseViewController which will be inherited from UIViewController. Import your category in this BaseViewController;

From this point, whenever you create a new viewController, select your base class type as BaseViewController not UIViewController.

By doing so, you can call that alert showing method from anywhere.